# Pyglet, how to make the ESCAPE key not close the window?

Tags: pyglet

I am writing a small sample program and I would like to override the default pyglet's behavioyr of ESC closing the app. I have something to the extent of:

```
window = pyglet.window.Window()
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.ESCAPE:
        pass
```

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Google group for [pyglet-users](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/pyglet-users) it is suggest could overload the window.Window.on_key_press(), although there are no code example of it.

Answer (score 24):

I know the question is old, but just in case. You've got to return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED to prevent default behaviour. I didn't test it, but in theory this should work:

```
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.ESCAPE:
        return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

Same for me. The question is old, but I've found out that you should use window handlers mechanisms, thus making the current event not to propagate further.

> You can prevent the remaining event
>   handlers in the stack from receiving
>   the event by returning a true value.
>   The following event handler, when
>   pushed onto the window, will prevent
>   the escape key from exiting the
>   program:

```
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.ESCAPE:
        return True

window.push_handlers(on_key_press)
```

Here is that [link](http://pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/stacking_event_handlers.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple actually, subclass Window and overide the on_key_press, like this:

```
class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):  
    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):  
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE:  
            return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED
```